# Proof Verification: Intersection of Sylow p-Subgroup and Normal Subgroup, Factor Group of Sylow p-Subgroup and Normal Subgroup

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Question:

Let $G$ be a finite group, let $p$ be a prime, and let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.  Moreover, let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$.  Show that $N \cap P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N$ and that $PN/N$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G/N$.  Is the first statement still true if $N$ is replaced by an arbitrary subgroup $H$ of $G$?

My Attempt:

Since $G$ is a finite group, let $|G|= p^am$ for some $a \in \mathbb{N}_0, m \in \mathbb{N}$ where $p \nmid m$.  $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, so by definition $\mid{P}\mid = p^a$. To show that $N \cap P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N$ we must prove that $N \cap P$ is a $p$-subgroup of $N$ such that $p$ does not divide $[N : P \cap N]$.

First note that in general the intersection of any collection of subgroups of $G$ is again a subgroup of $G$, so $N \cap P \leq G$.  We also have that $N \cap P \subseteq N$, and since $N \leq G$ we have $N \cap P \subseteq N \leq G$ so that $N \cap P \leq N$.  With the same reasoning we also have that $N \cap P \leq P$, and by Lagrange's Theorem we then know that $|N \cap P|$ must divide the order of $P$, which is $p^a$.  Since $p$ is a prime this means that $|N \cap P| = p^b$ for some $b \in \mathbb{N}_0, b \leq a$.  Hence $N \cap P$ is a subgroup of $N$ of order $p^b$ where $b \in \mathbb{N}_0$, i.e., $N \cap P$ is a $p$-subgroup of $N$.  To show that $P \cap N$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N$ now amounts to proving that $p$ does not divide $[N : P \cap N]$.

Now, since $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ we have that $NP = PN$, which implies that $NP \leq G$.  Since $G$ is finite, $N$ and $P$ are both finite subgroups of $G$ and we have the following relationship between the orders of the group:

$$
\lvert PN\rvert = \frac{\lvert P\rvert \cdot \lvert{N}\rvert}{\lvert P \cap N\rvert},
$$

which implies the equality

$$
\frac{\lvert PN\rvert}{\lvert P\rvert} = \frac{\lvert N\rvert}{\lvert P \cap N\rvert}.
$$

Clearly we have that $P \subseteq PN$, and since $PN \leq G$ we have $P \subseteq PN \leq G$ which gives that $P \leq PN$, hence we have $P \leq PN \leq G$.  By Lagrange we have

$$
|G| = [G: PN]|PN|,
$$
$$
|PN|= [PN:P]|P|,
$$
$$
|G| = [G:P]|P|,
$$

so by the first and last equalities we get that

$$
[G:PN][PN:P]|P| = [G:P]|P|,
$$

hence

$$
[G:PN][PN:P] = [G:P]
$$

hence

$$
\frac{\lvert G\rvert}{\lvert PN\rvert} \cdot \frac{\lvert PN\rvert}{\lvert P\rvert} = \frac{\lvert G\rvert}{\lvert P\rvert}.
$$

From our original assertions $|G|/|P| = p^am/p^a = m$ and $p \nmid m$, so if $p$ does not divide $|G|/|P|$ it certainly does not divide the left-hand side of the above equation, hence $p$ does not divide $|PN|/|P|$.  Recall that we proved the equality

$$
\frac{\lvert PN\rvert}{\lvert P\rvert} = \frac{\lvert N\rvert}{\lvert P \cap N\rvert},
$$

hence we also know that $p$ does not divide $\lvert N\rvert/\lvert N \cap P\rvert = [N:P \cap N]$, thus finishing the proof that $P \cap N$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N$.

To show that $PN/N$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G/N$ we must show that $PN/N \leq G/N$, that the order of $PN/N$ is some natural number power of $p$ and that $p$ does not divide $[G/N : PN/N]$.  Before doing so, we should verify that the coset $PN/N$ does indeed admit a group structure. We may do so by proving that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $PN$.  Let $n_1 \in N$ and let $pn_2 \in PN$.  Then

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        (pn_2)n_1(pn_2)^{-1} &= pn_2n_1n_2^{-1}p^{-1} \\[8pt]
        &= p(n_2n_1n_2^{-1})p^{-1} \in PNP^{-1},
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}

but recall that we have $PN = NP$, so $PNP^{-1} = N$ thus $p(n_2n_1n_2^{-1})p^{-1} \in N$ and we have shown that $N$ is closed under conjugation with elements from $PN$, thus $N \unlhd PN$ as claimed.  The fact that $PN/N \leq G/N$ follows from the Second Isomorphism Theorem since $PN \leq G$ and $N$ is contained in both $PN$ and $G$.  To show the order of this group, we combine the information we have shown above:

$$\begin{align}
|PN/N|&= [PN : N] \\
&= \frac{|PN|}{|N|} \\
&= |PN| \cdot \frac{1}{|N|}\\
& = \frac{|P|\cdot|N|}{|P \cap N|} \cdot \frac{1}{|N|}\\
& = \frac{|P|}{|P \cap N|} \\
&= \frac{p^a}{p^b} \\
&= p^{a-b},
\end{align}$$

so indeed $PN/N$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G/N$.  Finally, to show that $p$ does not divide $[G/N: PN/N]$ observe that we have

$$\begin{align}
[G/N : PN/N] &= \frac{|G/N|}{|PN/N|} \\
&= \frac{|G|}{|N|} \cdot \frac{|N|}{|PN|}\\
& = \frac{|G| \cdot |P \cap N|}{|P|\cdot |N|} \\
&= \frac{p^am \cdot |P \cap N|}{p^a \cdot |N|}\\
& = \frac{m \cdot |P \cap N|}{|N|}.
\end{align}$$

By assumption $p \nmid m$, but we also proved earlier that $p$ does not divide $|N|/|P \cap N|$, so $p$ certainly does not divide its reciprocal $|P \cap N|/|N|$ hence $p$ does not divide $m \cdot |P \cap N|/|N|$, i.e., $p \nmid [G/N : PN/N]$ and therefore we conclude that $PN/N$ is in fact a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G/N$.

The first statement is not necessarily true if $N$ is replaced by an arbitrary subgroup $H$ of $G$; consider the following counterexample:

Let $G = S_3$, the symmetric group on $3$ elements, $P = \langle (1 \thinspace 2) \rangle = \{(1 \thinspace 2), e\}$ and let $H = \langle (1 \thinspace 3) \rangle = \{(1 \thinspace 3), e\}$.  Note that $P$ is a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$ since the order of $P$ is $2$, and $2$ does not divide $[G : P] = 3$.  When we take the intersection we have $P \cap H = \{e\}$, but the order of this group does divide $[G : P \cap H] = 6$ hence $P \cap H$ is not a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$.

Comment: To your last question, yes, you should provide a counterexample. But this is easy enough, just think of a group $G$ with two *distinct*  $p$-Sylow subgroups $H, P$. But please note that the equality $\dfrac{|HP|}{|P|} = \dfrac{|H|}{|H \cap P|}$ holds true even if $H P$ is not a subgroup.

Comment: You could also benefit from the third isomorphism theorem, that tells you straight away that $[G/N : PN/N] = [G : PN]$, and then $[G : P] = [G : PN] \cdot [PN : P]$ tells you that $p$ does not divide $[G : PN]$, as $p$ does not divide $[G : P]$..

Comment: For the third isomorphism theorem, do we not need to have $PN \unlhd G$?  Here I have shown that $PN \leq G$ but not the stronger condition.  I'm guessing that it's true in general that if $N$ is normal in $G$ then $PN$ is also normal in $G$?

Comment: Added in counterexample based on your hint.